# When calculating joint probabilities using double integrals...

Tags: probability, integration

When calculating joint probabilities using double integrals, do we use $dx\ dy$ or $dy\ dx$ ? I thought it was the former, but then my book abruptly changes to using $dy\ dx$ without an explanation whatsoever. Some of the questions have the same answer no matter which variable you choose to integrate first, some do not.

In short, when calculating joint probabilities, do we use $dx\ dy$ or $dy\ dx$ ? And if possible, an explanation will be lovely! Thank you c:

One example where the order of integration matters is:

Find $P(X<2Y)$ if $f_{x,y}(x,y)=x+y$ for $X$ and $Y$ each defined over the unit interval.

The correct answer is $19/24$, which happens if you integrate wrt $y$ first. If you start with $x$, however, you get $4/3$. I'd like to know when exactly to use $dx\ dy$ or $dy\ dx$.

Comment: It just has an influence on the order of Integration, sometimes it is harder to integrate first for (say) $x$ then for $y$, sometimes it's the same. But the result shouldn't be any different !

Comment: Really? But this one gets different results :c

Find P(X<2Y) if fx,y(x,y)=x+y for X and Y each defined over the unit interval.

if you do dxdy, you get 4/3, while if you do dydx, you get 19/24

Comment: ... I'm sorry, what is a support?

Comment: I can't answer that, I'm sorry :(( what I typed up there was the whole problem in the exact words in was stated in.

Comment: Yes. That's how I got 19/24, which is apparently the correct answer.

Comment: Yep, did that, but I ended up with 4/3, which is incorrect :c correct answer is apparently 19/24, which we can get by integrating with respect to y first.

Comment: @OhDear Edit your question and write down what you tried.

Comment: Not sure if it helps since I don't need help with that specific question, but done!

Answer (score 0):

When changing the order of integration, the problem is finding the correct limits for the variables. One way to describe the area (the easiest one) is
$$
0 \leq x \leq 1\\
x/2 \leq y \leq 1
$$
which allows us to first integrate over $y$ and then $x$, since $x$ runs over its whole range and hence can be the outer integral. To integrate over $x$ first instead, $y$ needs to run over its whole range. But then the area is
$$
0 \leq y \leq 1\\
0 \leq x \leq 2y\\
 x \leq 1
$$
So here $x$ is bounded by several functions, so the integration will be somewhat more complicated. Note that you get $4/3$ as the answer if you integrate over
$$
0 \leq y \leq 1\\
0 \leq x \leq 2y\\
$$
but this is not the same area as the original one! You can see this for example by plotting the areas in wolfram.

More about changing the order of integration: [link](http://mathinsight.org/double_integral_change_order_integration_examples)